# Code Conversion

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

**I want to convert this vb into c#, I cant correct it**

```
Public Function encryptPassword(ByVal Password As String, ByVal Salt As String) As String
  Using HashTool As New SHA512Managed()
      Dim PasswordAsByte() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(String.Concat(Password, Salt))
      Dim EncryptedBytes() As Byte = HashTool.ComputeHash(PasswordAsByte)
      HashTool.Clear()
      Return Convert.ToBase64String(EncryptedBytes)
  End Using
End Function
```

**I was suggested this code, **

```
public string encryptPassword(string Password, string Salt) {
    Using;
    ((void)(HashTool));
    new SHA512Managed();
    byte[] PasswordAsByte = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string.Concat(Password, Salt));
    byte[] EncryptedBytes = HashTool.ComputeHash(PasswordAsByte);
    HashTool.Clear();
    return Convert.ToBase64String(EncryptedBytes);
}
```

**but it wasn't correct at all, please help**

Comment: http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/

Answer (score 4):

Not sure who suggested that code; it looks like a half-assed decompiler or conversion tool.  But it's pretty close, once you weed out the weirdness...apparently someone just doesn't know how to decompile a `using` block.  :P

```
public string encryptPassword(string Password, string Salt)
{
    using (var HashTool = new SHA512Managed())
    {
        byte[] PasswordAsByte = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string.Concat(Password, Salt));
        byte[] EncryptedBytes = HashTool.ComputeHash(PasswordAsByte);
        HashTool.Clear();
        return Convert.ToBase64String(EncryptedBytes);
    }
}
```

(Side note:  You're hashing, not encrypting.  `EncryptedBytes` is badly named.  Oh, and naming conventions say the variable names should start with a lowercase letter.)

Comment: @user1192078: Not a problem.  If this helped, feel free to click that checkbox next to the answer.  :)